# How to delete selected row from DataGridView and database in C#

Tags: c#

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

int i;
i = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);  
OleDbCommand delcmd = new OleDbCommand();
if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 1 && i != dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
{
      delcmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tb1 WHERE ID=" + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "";
      con.Open();
      delcmd.Connection = con;
      delcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      con.Close();
      dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Index);
      MessageBox.Show("Row Deleted");
}

}
```

this is my code for deleting the seleted row from  datagridview  and database but when i click on the delete button it is showing this error...

> "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size
>   of the collection. Parameter name: index"

Plz help me the code...

Comment: Where is the error thrown? Is it at `i = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0]` ?

Comment: this error is thrown at this command ... delcmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tb1 WHERE ID=" + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "";

Comment: Are you sure? Because you just commented a minute ago that it was `i = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0]` line.

Comment: yes i am sure it is showing error on the delete command line

Answer (score 2):

Exploring `DataGridView` manually to fill and then access data (I mean picking up values from cells), as well as ignoring `using` for disposables, as well as using string concatenation instead of parametrized queries, is a direct way to hell.

I strongly recommend you to use data binding and parametrized queries.
Declare an entity type, whose instances will be displayed in `DGV`:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Configure `DGV` columns to be data-bound (for the sample, set `DataPropertyName` property to "Id" and "Name" respectively) and set `DGV` data source:

```
        // your application fills this collection using data from database
        var source = new List<MyEntity>
        {
            new MyEntity { Id = 1, Name = "Apple" },
            new MyEntity { Id = 2, Name = "Orange" },
            new MyEntity { Id = 3, Name = "Plum" },
            new MyEntity { Id = 4, Name = "Peach" },
        };

        dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingList<MyEntity>(source);
```

When you want to delete item from `DGV`, use underlying data source instead of picking up data from the view:

```
    private void DeleteSelectedItem()
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        var itemToDelete = (MyEntity)dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;

        using (var connection = new OleDbConnection("..."))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (var command = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM tb1 WHERE ID = ?", connection))
            {
                // delete item from database
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", itemToDelete.Id);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // delete item from datasource and update DGV
                var dataSource = (BindingList<MyEntity>)dataGridView1.DataSource;
                dataSource.Remove(itemToDelete);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: note, that if you're using `DataTable` as the data source (I've read your comment), then the `DataBoundItem` is the `DataRow`, and the solution even simpler (you don't need any entity type). Just get the id value from the `DataRow` instance. And if you use `DataAdapter`, then you even don't need `DataBoundItem`. Just remove row from data table, and call `DataAdapter.Update(DataTable)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in this way  Follow the following steps
 1. Delete your row from DataBase
 2. Clear Datasource of Your DataGridview
 3. Select data from Database and set it to DataGridview

Answer (score 0):

> "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size
>   of the collection. Parameter name: index"

It means that you are accessing a location or index which is not present in collection.
When you click the delete button, verify whether any cell is selected.

```
if(dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
{ 
   i = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0] 
   OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);  
   OleDbCommand delcmd = new OleDbCommand();
   if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 1 && i != dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
   {
       delcmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tb1 WHERE ID=" + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "";
       con.Open();
       delcmd.Connection = con;
       delcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       con.Close();
       dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Index);
       MessageBox.Show("Row Deleted");
   }
}
else 
{
  MessageBox.Show("Please select a row");
}
```

Comment: i am showing data in datagridview like this... OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from tb1", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           da.Fill(dt);
          dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
is this the right way ??

Comment: i used your code..it is saying that i does not exist in the current context

Comment: Can you provide more clear picture where the "does not exist in the current context" message is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(cs))
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                int id =Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
                cmd.CommandText = "Delete from user where id='" + id+ "'";

                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: To improve your answer you should add some basic explanation. At least what you changed in the code and preferably why you changed it.